# How AutoFocus Textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem while developing my app - how can I auto-focus a textfield after completing input on the previous field, without having to click the textfield?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Use focusNode property and onEditingComplete event. Event trigger after user click on enter on first textfield, after that focusNode request focus for the second TextField.

For example:

```
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            autofocus: true,
            onEditingComplete: (() => focusNode.requestFocus())
          ),
          TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode,
          )
        ]
      )
    );
```

More info at: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/focus

Comment: thanks for respond but i try requestFocus() error ?

Comment: Not sure what problem do you have. It would be helpful if you copy paste the error that showed up. Anyway, I edited my answer so it should be more obvious what to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
  onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
),
```

For the last textfield you would change the 'nextFocus()' to 'unfocus()'

Answer (score 0):

```
return Focus(
  child: TextField(
    onChanged: (value) => context.read<SignupBloc>().add(SignupPasswordChanged(value)),
    controller: controller,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
    obscureText: true,
    key: const Key('signupForm_passwordInput_textField'),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Password *',
      errorText: state.password.invalid
          ? 'Passwords must be at least 10 characters in length\nand a minimum of 1 '
          'upper case and 1 lower case letter [A-Za-z]'
          : null,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try with

textInputAction: TextInputAction.next

in TextFormField